# Using friend in templates

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I am writing a small class, the class is basically a factory for the C class, but I want other classes to be able to access some of the methods.

```
template<class C>
class CFactory {
public:   
   friend class C;
};
```

This should make the fields of CFactory available to the class C, but the compiler thinks otherwise.

I'm getting the following two errors using gcc on a mac.

> error: using template type parameter 'C' after 'class'
>
> error: friend declaration does not name a class or function

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get et right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ise's response is correct -- [Comeau's FAQ](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#friendclassT) contains a question concerning this issue in more detail.

However, perhaps you can try an extra template indirection that might work? Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct FriendMaker
{
    typedef T Type;
};

template <typename T>
class CFactory
{
public:
    friend class FriendMaker<T>::Type;
};
```

This seems to only work with gcc 4.5.x however so I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, in my understanding, this isn't allowed in current standard.
§7.1.5.3/2 says:

> [Note: ... within a class template
>   with a template type-parameter T, the
>   declaration
>   friend class T;
>   is ill-formed. -end note]

On a related note, this restriction seems to be removed in C++0x
(§11.3/3 in N3290).
Incidentally, `MSVC` may allow this if we write simply `friend T;`.

Comment: Yes, "friend T;" is in C++11: https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/introduction-to-the-c11-feature-extended-friend-declaration-fanglu

Answer (score 3):

`C` can be anything - `int`, `double`, etc. and they are not classes. In general, this `class C` is not `class`. And you cannot have something like:

```
class A
{
    friend class int;
    //..
};
```

One more reason to prefer `typename`, instead of `class` when using `template`s

Comment: how do I tell the template that C is a class?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. The compiler could generate error if the template is instantiated with non-class. After all, that is how templates work in most cases.

Comment: You're actually right, but it seems like it's not allowed. My VS2010 says: `typename' is not a 'class'` even thought I used `class` in the template.

Comment: Kiril Kirov: How would one do a thing like this then? Is there no way of making sure the template argument is actually a class? Perhaps in c++x0?

Comment: What are you are really trying to do? What kind of template requires its template parameter to actually be a class?

Comment: I have no idea. This cannot be done in some standard way, but I'm pretty sure, that there's some trick about this.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: The `class` keyword in template code exists only for legacy reasons. In actual fact, they're all `typename`. You can pass `int` to a template expecting `class`.

Comment: @DeadMG - I know that, why you're telling me this ?

Comment: Argh, if it's because of my "even thought I used class in the template" - I added this "just in case" you know, if someone ask me - "what did you use - "typename" or "class" in the template" :)